# how to override the Image object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, closures, overriding, xss

I want to override the window.Image object for detected some XSS Attack on browser.
see the code:

```
(function(){
    if(typeof(window.Image)!=="object"){
        var _original_Image=new Image();
        Object.defineProperty(_original_Image,'src', {
            set: function(srcAttr){
                if(/document\.cookie/.test(srcAttr)){console.log('cookie attack!')};
                _original_Image.setAttribute('src',srcAttr);
            },
            get: function(){return _original_Image.src};
        })
        window.Image = function(){ return _original_Image };
        return _original_Image;
    }
}())
```

run it.

```
>>> a = new Image()
<img>
>>> a.src="document.cookie"
cookie attack!
GET http://192.168.0.2/document.cookie 404 (Not Found) 
>>> document.body.appendChild(a)
<img src="document.cookie">
```

the image was successful appended.

but there's some problem.see

```
>>> b = new Image()
<img src="document.cookie">
```

it menas the original HTMLImageElement is changed, it will have the last img elements' attrubutes.

I want to it return `<img>` only. how to?

Answer (score 1):

We should be overriding the Image object that is being created and not the native Image object itself which is what you are doing. It should look like this:

```
(function () {
    var NativeImage;

    var createImage = function () {
        var image = new NativeImage(arguments);

        Object.defineProperty(image, 'src', {
            set: function (srcAttr) {
                // whatever else you want to put in here
                image.setAttribute('src',srcAttr);
            },
            get: function () {
                return image.src;
            }
        });

        return image;
    };

    if (typeof window.Image !== 'object') {
        NativeImage = window.Image;
        window.Image = function () {
            return createImage.call(this, arguments) ;
        };
    }
}());
```